# Retrieving data from Microsoft SQL Server Database with C# Restful web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I have been trying to retrieve data from Microsoft SQL Server Database with a web service. My aim is, for example, after keying in a url like `localhost/TestWebsite/api/Readings`, I would be able to retrieve data in `json/xml` format from the database. However, I am now encountering this after a while:

[image]

I looked up on the web and it stated that what was shown above is not actually an error.

How do I determine if whether the web service is connected to the database?

**Code for database connection in web.config file:**

```
<add name="SecondlyReadingsContext" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=cloudsql;user=xxx;password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,

Why not make a test of your database connection in your web services.
Make a method that will log response from your database.
And kindly show your code if you have some.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your connection is working OK, as you're being returned some XML.

Assuming that you expect to be able to present this data somehow, now you need to ensure that the output is handled the way you want. If you want to be able to actually display the data on a web page, you need some JavaScript that makes an Ajax call to that URL, then with the 'data' that comes back, you can present it on the page (there are lots of way to easily convert json or XML into deserialized data that you can present in your front end)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know of any tutorial that teaches how to convert json/xml data into deserialized data?